# Solr How to delete all records EXCEPT ones in an array?

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, solr

I have a SolrPhpClient which I use to communicate with Solr.

I can make queries very easy, like:

```
    $solr->deleteByQuery("id: 12345")
```

Anyways, I wonder if anybody out there know of a way to delete all records in a Solr index EXCEPT ones I have inside an array...

Is this even possible...

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$solr->deleteByQuery("*:* -id:(12345 OR 12346 OR 12347)")
```